# Other galaxies in "A Fire Upon the Deep"

Tags: zones-of-thought, a-fire-upon-the-deep

In [*A Fire Upon the Deep*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1952) at the beginning I distinctly remember a mention to the Sculptor Galaxy.

Do they ever make another reference to a galaxy outside the Milky Way, or is this the only one?

Answer (score 11):

Large and small Magellanics count as galaxies despite being satellites of the Milky way:

> Relay was now the main intermediate to the Magellanics, and one of the
>   few sites with any sort of link to the Beyond in Sculptor.

Searching on the term galaxy turns up just those three, plus the Milky Way.
Sculptor itself may be a ref to the [constellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sculptor_%28constellation%29) (area of sky) rather than a particular galaxy or galaxy group.

Answer (score -1):

No, there are no references to anything outside of the Milky Way galaxy (and we know that it's the Milky Way because humans exist within it, humans from Earth).

When it talks about the gods/deities from the Transcend, it mentions that they tend to stay away from the intergalactic void, and Vinge hints there are things even more powerful than them.

Comment: Question about your answer here; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/234862/references-to-beyond-the-transcend

Comment: @Valorum Validating my answer, which still has -4 votes. I hate this place, you're all bad at questions and answers and none of you deserve me.

Comment: If you post an answer that's long on supposition and short on evidence, you're gonna get downvotes